Raydium swap with rust
Does anyone have some practical examples of swapping on Raydium using Rust?
If you have any examples you can share please

Check out the Anchor CPI examples in this repo
https://github.com/raydium-io/raydium-cpi-example

I am looking for same kind of question, I found the Raydium code on the Github. Have someone integrated with their smart contract (program) buy/sell? I want this?
I am also looking for the code for the Mateora Dex for their Dynamic Pools to be integrated with my custom Anchor Rust Program ?
Mateora Dynamic pool link
The github for mateora
